# Converting from C++, C#, Perl, or Java to PHP

Tags: c#, java, php, c++, perl

As the following link shows, NCBI (National Center for Biotechnology Information) has provided a small yet very useful SOAP client for bioinformatics in C++, C#, Perl and Java but unfortunately there's no PHP version of this SOAP client.

ftp://lucid.bic.nus.edu.sg/biomirrors/blast/web_services/

Here is a part of Perl SOAP client that helps us BLAST a genetic sequence:

```
    my $search_lite = SOAP::Data->value(
        SOAP::Data->name('options' => 
                         \SOAP::Data->value(
        SOAP::Data->name('Blast4-options-lite' =>
                         \SOAP::Data->name('task' => 'blastn'))
                         )))->uri(NCBI_XML_NAMESPACE);

    my $result = 
        $soap->call(SOAP::Data->name('Blast4-queue-search-request-lite')
                          ->uri(NCBI_XML_NAMESPACE)
                          => $search_lite);
```

I tried to convert it to PHP but it doesn't work. I also used this guideline: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK55699/

Here is my PHP code:

```
try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl);

    $result = $soapClient->SubmitSearchLite(array(
        //????
    ));
    echo $result;
}
catch {}
```

Could you please help me fix it?

Comment: It says: "Error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'options' property"

Comment: Why don't you set the option?

Comment: OP: You need to set the same information in the SubmitSearchLite as you do in your first example. You are missing the information about option

Comment: Thank you chac. Thank you OptimusCrime.The value of "options" is complicated. I don't know how to convert it to PHP!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)? It should allow you to consume the webservice through Java and then send whatever information you have to your PHP application:

> The PHP/Java Bridge is an implementation of a streaming, XML-based
>   network protocol, which can be used to connect a native script engine,
>   for example PHP, Scheme or Python, with a Java virtual machine. It is
>   up to 50 times faster than local RPC via SOAP, requires less resources
>   on the web-server side. It is faster and more reliable than direct
>   communication via the Java Native Interface, and it requires no
>   additional components to invoke Java procedures from PHP or PHP
>   procedures from Java.

This extra layer between the webservice and your PHP application would prove itself useful should there need to be any extra changes in the webservice since you would, most likely only need to mess around the Java layer, keeping your PHP code intact.

Answer (score -1):

You do know PHP has its own SOAP client, right?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know how to use this SOAP-based BLAST web service: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK55699/